# what is the purpose of angle brackers in the Java Class constructor?

Tags: java, class, generic-type-argument

I want method `public void x(List<Class<some expression>> m)` to throw an error if you try to pass a class which does not extend `class A{}` by replacing "some expression" with... some expression.

I always get an annoying warning when I use a wildcard or don't include it, so I would like to understand why Class deserves a dimension at all, even if I'm totally off base as to how it's used.

Comment: please paste full code

Comment: You should probably reread the [Java tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) and [Angelika Langer's FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) - I'm fairly sure they go over this. Then make a more specific question with examples of what kind of code you want to work or not ork.

Comment: that is the full code...

Comment: `public void x(List<Class<? extends A>> m)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly get what you want to do. Actually, this method signature:

```
public void x(List<? extends YourClass> m)
```

will not compile if you pass a `List` of objects whose class doesn't extend `YourClass` (let's call it so, instead of `A`).

If you want your `x` method to get, as a parameter, a list of `Class` objects, that's another issue. Are you sure you are not willing to just pass a `List` of objects of a class that extends `YourClass`? If so, that method signature should work.

**EDIT**: Since you stated you want to pass a list of classes, then this should work:

```
public void x(List<Class<? extends YourClass>> m)
```

Tested this way:

```
import java.util.*;

class YourClass {}
class YourClassEx extends YourClass {}

public class Test {

    public static void x(List<Class<? extends YourClass>> m) {
        // stuff...
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        List<Class<? extends YourClass>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(YourClass.class);
        list.add(YourClassEx.class);
        x(list); // compiles fine until here

        list.add(String.class); // doesn't compile
        x(new ArrayList<Class>()); // doesn't compile, either

    }
}
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, clearly I think, x takes a list of Class Objects.